# how do i make custom file that acts like an secured folder that only my rust app can access, with a password

Tags: rust

I'm making an emulated os that uses a browser to render and a abstraction of file system to allow apps to access their folders only. However, since it's an layer on top of real os (like linux or windows), a dangerous app running on real os can grab tokens and stuff from my emulated os' folder. How to i make a cross platform solution to stop from happening this?

Comment: Maybe the one way is to use in-house encoding/decoding?

Comment: Are you worried about a dangerous app running as root, or some other user? It seems like if normal filesystem permissions are insufficent then there are already serious security concerns with what you're doing, with or without the extra emulation part.

Comment: To complete @loganfsmyth's comment: if you are trying to prevent *anyone* from accessing your directory, besides your Rust application, then it's impossible (you cannot prevent root from accessing something). You can, at most, try to obfuscate data, but it's not reliable (a persevering attacker would bypass it). Also, keep in mind that at some point you'll have to read that data (unencrypted, unobfuscated), that is, load it in RAM, and then your at risk again, because root can read your process' RAM (and write on it). TL;DR you **must** trust root not trying to screw you.

Comment: That part is upto to the user himself . I just want to have basic security. The user himself will provide a password at my app's startup which will be used to read secured folder.

Comment: I feel my app has something to do with virtual filesystem in order to encrypt files and folders. Most likely I would have to make encfs alternative..

Comment: @RovelStars There is gocryptfs too, but that doesn't change what others have said. If your goal is to hide stuff from the host OS then you simply can't -- your decryption key has to exist in memory somewhere.

Comment: Check out [`keyring`](https://crates.io/crates/keyring), for each supported OS it lets you store credentials in the platform's built-in password manager.

Comment: @Coder-256 if I'm making my own version of keyring, that allows to even store big files, i wouldn't probably use the native keyring.